# How to make nginx to stop processing other rules and serve a specific location?

Tags: nginx

I have this config that works as expected in an empty `server { }` definition

```regex
location ^~ /foo/ {
    alias /var/www/foo/;
}
```

But when I move this in a considerably bigger server definition (one used for a WordPress multi-site config), it will stop  working and wordpress will respond to it (which obviously was not my intent).

I tried to put at the begining or end of server block, but this didn't change it.

How can I force Nginx to use this location?

Answer (score 28):

You are probably looking for `break`.

```regex
location ^~ /foo/ {
    alias /var/www/foo/;
    break;
}
```

From the [`HttpRewriteModule` documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule):

> `last` - completes processing of current rewrite directives and
>   restarts the process (including rewriting) with a search for a match
>   on the URI from all available locations.
>
> `break` - completes processing of current rewrite directives and
>   non-rewrite processing continues within the current location block
>   only.
>
> Note that outside location blocks, last and break are effectively the
>   same.

Comment: It is for the rewrite rules, and not for the location directives.

Comment: In fact, `break` is what saved my config from the rewrite module going beyond my `^~` location and processing my php rewrite regexp when i did not want it to.

Answer (score 4):

Location blocks in Nginx are exclusive. If you use `location ^~` then other rules probably expiry headers for static objects will not apply unless you copy those rules as nested under the same location block.

If you could share your full config then I can make it work for you. Most likely you need to use nested location blocks.

Comment: Your second sentence is undecipherable.

Comment: I mean if expiry headers are listed under a separate common block, then they won't apply to this block that is using `location ^~`

Answer (score 0):

```
location = /aliasname/ { 
  alias /path/to/alias/
}
```

Trailing slash will be a problem if it is not present in URI.
See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#matching-location-blocks