# Nginx location "not equal to" regex

Tags: regex, nginx, webserver

How do I set a `location` condition in Nginx that responds to anything that isn't equal to the listed locations?

I tried:

```
location !~/(dir1|file2\.php) {
   rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

But it doesn't trigger the redirect.  It simply handles the requested URI using the rules in the rest of the server configuration.

Comment: I don't get it. For example user goes to `/aabbcc` and where are you going to redirect him?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159108/nginx-url-rewrite-using-negative-regex

Comment: this is also can be applied to location directive `location ~ ^/(?!(dir1|file2\.php)) {}`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

According to [*nginx* documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location)

> there is no syntax for NOT matching a regular expression. Instead, match the target regular expression and assign an empty block, then use location / to match anything else

So you could define something like

```
location ~ (dir1|file2\.php) { 
    # empty
}

location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 permanent; 
}
```

Comment: Worth noting: I needed this to conditionally redirect a hostname and had some more `location`s next to the redirecting one. The redirect wasn't working. Turns out I had to add a `break;` directive as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049884

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work when you want to proxy_pass requests in first location because proxy_pass doesn't support regexps

Comment: I get that the doc says `there is no syntax for NOT matching` however ~ ^/(?!(text or pattern not to match)) is valid regex and more importantly works.

Comment: There is a syntax for not matching. And there is a operator that not produces a match with a given subregex

Comment: i want rule, if someone enter "/api/123" it should return 403, everything except "/api/" shoud return 403

Answer (score 87):

i was looking for the same. and found this solution.

**Use negative regex assertion:**

```
location ~ ^/(?!(favicon\.ico|resources|robots\.txt)) { 
.... # your stuff 
}
```

Source
[Negated Regular Expressions in location](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?10,230949,238999#msg-238999)

Explanation of Regex :

If URL does not match any of the following path

```
example.com/favicon.ico
example.com/resources
example.com/robots.txt
```

Then it will go inside that location block and will process it.

Comment: This working well. Example:
location ~ (/konference(?!/20))
catch /konference,/konference/images/
NOT catch /konference/2015, /konferece/2015/images
tested on Nginx 1.10.2

Comment: How to extract variable if needed? I want to know what is the slug so I can pass it to a proxy pass.

Comment: @ApoorvNag i dont know, try creating new question. thanks

Comment: really useful. EG catch any php file except index `location ~ /public/(?!index.php$)+.*\.php$ {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /public/index.php?url=$1;
        }`

Comment: @AMB Can you provide an explanation of the regex? I didn't get it even after reading the source link.

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha please check updated answer, if you want more explanation, feel free to reply.

Comment: This was super helpful, running multiple services in docker behind an nginx. With your post I was able to have a static client at / by tweaking your rule a little. Thanks!    location ~ ^/(?!(grafana|gateway)) { root /etc/nginx/html/client; try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html  =404; }

Comment: This should be flagged as the correct answer.it works like a charm using one location block only.

Answer (score 2):

As of 22-JAN-2023, nginx documentation states that `!~` and `!~*` are valid operators, although it doesn't mention since which version they're available. See the [documentation reference](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if:%7E:text=Negative%20operators%20%E2%80%9C!%7E%E2%80%9D%20and%20%E2%80%9C!%7E*%E2%80%9D%20are%20also%20available)

Comment: Negative operators are only available for `if` statements. Not for location detectives.