# url rewrite with nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to rewrite `http://www.mydomain.com/xxxxx` to `http://www.mydomain.com/page1.php?h=xxxxx`

I use this rule

```
rewrite /([a-z1-9]+)$ /page1.php?h=$1 last;
```

it redirect correctly to `page1.php`

but after clicking a link in `(page1.php?h=xxxxx)` to go to `(page2.php?h=xxxxx)`

it redirects to the same page `(page1.php?h=xxxxx)` and not enter `(page2.php?h=xxxxx)`

I don't know why, can any one help me?

thanks

Comment: aren't you always rewriting to page1.php???

Comment: yes, so what can I do

Comment: but when in page1.php I don't want to run the rewrite rule

Comment: @Mas: I would take a look at this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16304073/398519

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the below will not work due to nginx locations not allowing negative matching. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16304073/398519 )

> Ok if switching the setup is not an option than you will need a location, something like:
>
> ```
> location !~* \.php$ {
>     rewrite /([a-z1-9]+)$ /page1.php?h=$1 last;
> }
> ```
>
> I believe (not tested) that it should not match `.php` or any other item with a `.ext` and should only pull from the webroot portion. I am not able to test it at this time unfortunately.

---

For starters your initial rule is too vague. You need something to distinguish whats goes to page 1 and what goes to page 2.

Such as:  `http://www.domain.com/p1/xxxxxxx`

That way you can parse at the p1 / p2 etc and know how to handle it. For completeness, here are some example rules:

```
rewrite /p1/([a-z1-9]+)$ /page1.php?h=$1 last;
rewrite /p2/([a-z1-9]+)$ /page2.php?h=$1 last;
```

If you want to use your original rule, then you need to add a file check and or change the regex to not match `.php` or `.whatever`  I am not sure how to do this on nginx other than creating a `location`  section before the root location so it gets trapped there first.

Comment: ok thanks but I already have a script running and generating short links I just changed apache to nginx so rewrite rules also changed, so I just want the rule to transfer the hash when linked to the domain only

Comment: @Mas Just updated it with a location rule, hopefully that works.

Comment: @Mas, ok, I made it a bit simpler, try that. It should redirect anything that does not have a .php after it.

Comment: it gives me this message (nginx: [emerg] invalid location modifier "!~*" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:50) @Brad F Jacobs