# How to add slash to the end of every url except extensions?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, php

Need help.

How to add slash to the end of every url except extensions?

I tied to use

```
rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

It is working but adding slash to the end of **every** URL including css, js, images...

Comment: What for you want this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you. Sadly we do not have a syntax for `NOT` in Nginx, so we have to make an empty match and then use / to match anything else.

```
location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|htc|ico|png|html|xml)$ {
    # empty
}
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
}
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302897/nginx-location-not-equal-to-regex).