# Negative lookbehind in nginx location block

Tags: regex, nginx

I need to create a virtual sub directory in nginx which will serve files from a different location than the root. This virtual directory also runs PHP, but I've omitted the fastcgi config for brevity.

I have two location blocks, the one for the /virtual directory uses alias, while the location block for / has it's own root directive. This root directive gets inherited by the virtual folder, messing up the paths. Is there any way I can exclude urls in /virtual from inheriting the root directive of the / location block?

Here is an excerpt of my server config:

```
server {
    root /path/to;

    location ^~ /virtual/ {
        alias /path/to/lions/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /lions/public/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location / {
        root /path/to/tigers/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

If I browse to hostname/virtual/whatever, nginx looks for the file at

```
/path/to/tigers/public/lions/public/whatever
```

instead of

```
/path/to/lions/public/whatever
```

I have tried the following pattern to match all urls at / except for those starting with /virtual, but that didn't match anything.

```
location ^~ ((?!\/virtual)\/.*)$
```

I have also tried putting both an alias and a root directive in the location block for /virtual, but nginx wouldn't start.

Is there any other way to have a different root for my alias directory?

Comment: Try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16304073/3832970).  Use `location ~ ^/?virtual/.*$ { # empty }` and then use `location / { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `location` and the value of the `alias` should either both end in `/` or neither end in `/` - due to the way `nginx` does the text substitution when calculating the `$request_filename`.

All elements in the `try_files` statement are URIs, so your final element should be `/virtual/index.php?$query_string` and not `/lions/public/index.php?$query_string`. The latter would begin a new search, which would be processed by the `location /` block. Hence the strange file path.

Finally, there is an unpredictability when using `alias` and `try_files` together. See [this bug report](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). The same functionality can be achieved using a `if` block. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

For example:

```
location ^~ /virtual/ {
    alias /path/to/lions/public/;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /virtual/index.php?$query_string; }
}
```