Problem in vue nginx.conf, requests are not working
there is such a code
const urls = {
  users: "/users/api/v1/user",
  roles: "/users/api/v1/role",
};

and
location /users/ {
    proxy_pass  https://$USER_URL/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_intercept_errors  off;
    proxy_buffer_size       4k;
    proxy_buffers           4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    proxy_read_timeout 120;
    proxy_connect_timeout 120;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
  }

location /api/ {
    proxy_pass  https://$BACKEND_URL/api/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_intercept_errors  off;
    proxy_buffer_size       4k;
    proxy_buffers           4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    proxy_read_timeout 120;
    proxy_connect_timeout 120;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
  }

but for some reason it redirects me to location /api/, has anyone encountered this problem?
I tried to write the location separately, tried to change the paths but it didn’t work, although other methods of the service (location /users/) work, here
const urls = {
  login: "/users/api/v1/auth/login",
  refreshToken: "/users/api/v1/auth/refresh",
  validate: "/users/api/v1/auth/validate",
  change_pwd: "/users/api/v1/auth/change-password",
};


Looks like location /api/ is applied after /users/. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699755/how-to-make-nginx-to-stop-processing-other-rules-and-serve-a-specific-location

Could you please provide more details? I just don't know nginx very well
